# Count of accepted answers?

Tags: discussion

Is there a way to know total number of accepted answers vs. total number of answer given.

Though Total number of answers we find from profile.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest way is to do a search:

```
user:<user_id> is:answer                // denominator
user:<user_id> is:answer isaccepted:yes // numerator
user:<user_id> is:answer deleted:yes    // possibly adjust for this value
```

I used this approach to modify the results of the below query linked from the Data Explorer.

```
UserId  Answers  Deleted  Accepted  Accept%  Delete%
====================================================
 18731      545      222       390     50.8     28.9
    67      243        5       155     62.5      2.0
   144      134        6        85     60.7      4.3
 20830      151       11        95     58.6      6.8
  5460      185       10       113     57.9      5.1
  2984     3854      119      2181     54.9      3.0
   286      519        6       289     55.0      1.1
  2995     2099      163      1141     50.4      7.2
 30686      135       12        72     49.0      8.2
 24975      124       23        66     44.9     15.6
   660      351       11       184     50.8      3.0
   293      214       14       110     48.2      6.1
  3038      294       12       150     49.0      3.9
   416      345        7       176     50.0      2.0
  2832      109        3        55     49.1      2.7
 26224      208       29       103     43.5     12.2
  4136      238       27       117     44.2     10.2
    60      200        3        98     48.3      1.5
   154      354       10       172     47.3      2.7
   887     2145      131      1025     45.0      5.8
  3996     1414      165       670     42.4     10.4
  3277      436       22       206     45.0      4.8
   843      236        5       111     46.1      2.1
 10382      100        8        47     43.5      7.4
   102     1196       28       561     45.8      2.3
    87      310        6       143     45.3      1.9
  4726      237       27       109     41.3     10.2
  5449      255        9       117     44.3      3.4
    93      382       18       173     43.3      4.5
 12730      129        5        58     43.3      3.7
   642      377        7       169     44.0      1.8
 18261      114       12        51     40.5      9.5
   550      340       17       150     42.0      4.8
   984      470       18       206     42.2      3.7
   582      329       48       143     37.9     12.7
  5202      712       25       308     41.8      3.4
   605      229        7        99     41.9      3.0
   799      471       13       203     41.9      2.7
   165      107       11        46     39.0      9.3
 17316      335       22       142     39.8      6.2
  5080      151        0        64     42.4      0.0
   645     1577      161       663     38.1      9.3
  2279      295        7       122     40.4      2.3
   320      322       28       133     38.0      8.0
 20832      239       11        98     39.2      4.4
  3390      122       12        50     37.3      9.0
 11239      706       88       289     36.4     11.1
   142      279       20       114     38.1      6.7
 24889      307        6       125     39.9      1.9
  4786      208        6        84     39.3      2.8
 12634      191        6        76     38.6      3.0
   594      291        5       113     38.2      1.7
   171      321       19       124     36.5      5.6
  2602     1101       20       425     37.9      1.8
   359      117        8        45     36.0      6.4
 20941      287       52       110     32.4     15.3
 10038      381       25       146     36.0      6.2
 11928      118       11        45     34.9      8.5
 36359      122       15        46     33.6     10.9
  4618      194       12        73     35.4      5.8
  4517      144       12        54     34.6      7.7
 18875      190       13        71     35.0      6.4
 33230      704       60       263     34.4      7.9
 21181      161        7        60     35.7      4.2
  2752      156        1        58     36.9      0.6
 22232      192       23        71     33.0     10.7
    98      187        1        69     36.7      0.5
   708      194        3        71     36.0      1.5
 11101      454       18       166     35.2      3.8
  7419      178        1        65     36.3      0.6
  4757      192        9        70     34.8      4.5
   498      321        9       117     35.5      2.7
 12627      123       14        44     32.1     10.2
   428      258       17        92     33.5      6.2
  3512      767       40       270     33.5      5.0
 20721      126       10        44     32.4      7.4
    78      472       18       162     33.1      3.7
   289      152        4        51     32.7      2.6
   177      141        2        47     32.9      1.4
   783      102        2        34     32.7      1.9
 16963      175        6        58     32.0      3.3
   421      160        4        53     32.3      2.4
   353      233       12        75     30.6      4.9
  2590      100        3        32     31.1      2.9
 10881      342        5       108     31.1      1.4
  9807      108        6        34     29.8      5.3
  9937      281       20        88     29.2      6.6
 11119      127       10        39     28.5      7.3
   192      127       12        39     28.1      8.6
   119      222       28        68     27.2     11.2
   267      149        5        45     29.2      3.2
  4773      346       49       100     25.3     12.4
 10062      104        2        30     28.3      1.9
  2535      181        8        52     27.5      4.2
 13196      163        4        45     26.9      2.4
    25      136        8        37     25.7      5.6
 11038      107        3        29     26.4      2.7
  3923      196       17        53     24.9      8.0
 19118      100       10        27     24.5      9.1
 26738      124        3        33     26.0      2.4
```

Take a look at [Users with highest accept rate of their answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/query/1433/users-with-highest-accept-rate-of-their-answers). Here is the raw dump of users with at least 100 posts (not adjusted for deleted posts):

```
User Link    NumAnswers    NumAccepted    AcceptedPercent
=========================================================
    18731           545            390    71.559633027522
       67           243            155    63.786008230452
      144           134             85    63.432835820895
    20830           151             95    62.913907284768
     5460           185            113    61.081081081081
     2984          3854           2181    56.590555267254
      286           519            289    55.684007707129
     2995          2099           1141    54.359218675559
    30686           135             72    53.333333333333
    24975           124             66    53.225806451612
      660           351            184    52.421652421652
      293           214            110    51.401869158878
     3038           294            150    51.020408163265
      416           345            176    51.014492753623
     2832           109             55     50.45871559633
    26224           208            103     49.51923076923
     4136           238            117    49.159663865546
       60           200             98                 49
      154           354            172    48.587570621468
      887          2145           1025    47.785547785547
     3996          1414            670    47.383309759547
     3277           436            206    47.247706422018
      843           236            111    47.033898305084
    10382           100             47                 47
      102          1196            561     46.90635451505
       87           310            143    46.129032258064
     4726           237            109    45.991561181434
     5449           255            117    45.882352941176
       93           382            173    45.287958115183
    12730           129             58    44.961240310077
      642           377            169    44.827586206896
    18261           114             51    44.736842105263
      550           340            150    44.117647058823
      984           470            206    43.829787234042
      582           329            143    43.465045592705
     5202           712            308    43.258426966292
      605           229             99    43.231441048034
      799           471            203    43.099787685774
      165           107             46    42.990654205607
    17316           335            142    42.388059701492
     5080           151             64    42.384105960264
      645          1577            663    42.041851616994
     2279           295            122    41.355932203389
      320           322            133    41.304347826086
    20832           239             98    41.004184100418
     3390           122             50    40.983606557377
    11239           706            289    40.934844192634
      142           279            114    40.860215053763
    24889           307            125     40.71661237785
     4786           208             84    40.384615384615
    12634           191             76     39.79057591623
      594           291            113    38.831615120274
      171           321            124    38.629283489096
     2602          1101            425    38.601271571298
      359           117             45    38.461538461538
    20941           287            110    38.327526132404
    10038           381            146    38.320209973753
    11928           118             45    38.135593220338
    36359           122             46    37.704918032786
     4618           194             73    37.628865979381
     4517           144             54               37.5
    18875           190             71    37.368421052631
    33230           704            263    37.357954545454
    21181           161             60    37.267080745341
     2752           156             58    37.179487179487
    22232           192             71    36.979166666666
       98           187             69    36.898395721925
      708           194             71    36.597938144329
    11101           454            166    36.563876651982
     7419           178             65    36.516853932584
     4757           192             70    36.458333333333
      498           321            117    36.448598130841
    12627           123             44    35.772357723577
      428           258             92    35.658914728682
     3512           767            270    35.202086049543
    20721           126             44    34.920634920634
       78           472            162    34.322033898305
      289           152             51    33.552631578947
      177           141             47    33.333333333333
      783           102             34    33.333333333333
    16963           175             58    33.142857142857
      421           160             53             33.125
      353           233             75    32.188841201716
     2590           100             32                 32
    10881           342            108    31.578947368421
     9807           108             34    31.481481481481
     9937           281             88    31.316725978647
    11119           127             39    30.708661417322
      192           127             39    30.708661417322
      119           222             68     30.63063063063
      267           149             45    30.201342281879
     4773           346            100    28.901734104046
    10062           104             30    28.846153846153
     2535           181             52    28.729281767955
    13196           163             45     27.60736196319
       25           136             37    27.205882352941
    11038           107             29    27.102803738317
     3923           196             53     27.04081632653
    19118           100             27                 27
    26738           124             33    26.612903225806
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try this query at data explorer. It will give you % of Accepted answer using that you can get the actual count. Just pass your used Id and get the count.

[What is my accepted answer percentage rate](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/949/what-is-my-accepted-answer-percentage-rate)

Answer (score 2):

The search parameter `isaccepted:yes` can be used to find accepted answers. Combine it with `user:me` to get the count of your accepted answers, or put numeric user Id to get someone else's.

Example: [search for your accepted answers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=isaccepted%3Ayes+user%3Ame).